# Proof for the series $\ln{x} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^k,\ \forall x>\frac12 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

The equation only came from my observation via brute force, graph, and Wolfram|Alpha, but I do not know where it exactly came from, except that I noticed in my attempts to prove this that it resembles the Taylor Series of $\ln(x)$ centered at $1$.

$$\ln{x} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^k,\ \forall x>\frac12 $$

Thank you!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  This didn't come out very well; I see a blotch in the middle of the formula.  Please use MathJax to format your questions.  If you need help, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Did you mean $$\ln{x} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^k,\ \forall x>\frac12 ?$$

Comment: Yes, I am new to this, and I am very sorry

Comment: Have I got the formula right?  It's obviously false when $x=1$  Maybe it should be $x-1$ instead of $x+1$?

Comment: Oh, my bad, it is x-1

Comment: The Taylor series of $\ln x$ works for $x \in (0,2)$. But if $x > 1/2$, $\ln x = - \ln(1/x)$ and $1/x \in (0,2)$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2740632/721644

Comment: I am quite familiar with that domain, but I am curious on how my question was related to the general formula of the Taylor series of $\ln{x} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$f(y)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{y^k}k,\ |y|<1$$  Then $f(0) = 0$ and $$f'(y)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty y^{k-1}=\frac1{1-y}$$  so that $$f(y)=\int_0^y\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1-x}=-\ln(1-y)$$  Now if $\ln{x}=-\ln(1-y)$, then $x=\frac1{1-y}$ or $y=\frac{x-1}{x}$.  This gives your formula, vaild when $$\left|\frac{x-1}{x}\right|<1,$$ that is, when $x>\frac12$.

Comment: Thank you so much! But may I ask if it's related to the general formula of the Taylor series of $\ln{x} $?

Comment: Yes, essentially we're starting with $$\ln(1-y)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{y^k}k.$$  Substitute $x=1-y$ to get the Taylor for $\ln x$ about $x=1$.

Comment: Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let $ n $ ne a positive integer and $ x $ a real such that $ \left|x\right|<1 \cdot $

\begin{aligned} \sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{x^{k}}{k}}+\ln{\left(1-x\right)}&=\int_{0}^{x}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{t^{k-1}}\,\mathrm{d}t}-\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t}}\\ &=\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{1-t^{n}}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t}-\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t}}\\ \sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{x^{k}}{k}}+\ln{\left(1-x\right)}&=-\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{t^{n}}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t} \end{aligned}

Meaning, \begin{aligned}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{x^{k}}{k}}+\ln{\left(1-x\right)}\right|=\left|\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{t^{n}}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t}\right|\leq\left|x\right|^{n}\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t}}\leq\left|x\right|^{n}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t}}=\left|x\right|^{n}\ln{2}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\end{aligned}

And thus, $$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^{n}}{n}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{x^{k}}{k}}}=-\ln{\left(1-x\right)} $$

For $ x>\frac{1}{2} $, setting $ x\leftarrow\frac{x-1}{x}<1 $, we get : $$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{n}}=-\ln{\left(1-\frac{x-1}{x}\right)}=\ln{x} $$

Comment: Where did the inequality after $$\lvert {\int_{0}^x \frac{t^n}{1-t} dt} \rvert $$ came from?